# Python How to print list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print list of list in python 3.x with below code, but it is giving an error.

```
lol=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],['five','six']]
for elem in lol:
      print (":".join(elem))
# this is the error I am getting-> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

I am expecting this output:

```
1:2
3:4
5:6
five:six
```

I could achieve the same output using below perl code (this is just for reference):

```
for (my $i=0;$i<scalar(@{$lol});$i++)
{
    print join(":",@{$lol->[$i]})."\n";
}
```

How do I do it in python 3.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can't join `int`'s only strings. You can Explicitly cast to `str` all your data
try something like this

```
for elem in lol:
    print (":".join(map(str, elem)))
```

or with generator

```
for elem in lol:
    print (":".join(str(i) for i in elem))
```

or You can use `format` instead of casting to string (this allows You to use complex formatting)

```
for elem in lol:
    print (":".join("'{}'".format(i) for i in elem))
```

Comment: That's a comprehension, not a generator.

Comment: `str.join` converts the genexp into a list first before actually joining them. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/846892

Comment: this is internal implementation of join as I understand. `":".join(str(i) for i in elem)` itself is generator

Comment: @oleg: More precisely, the `str(i) for i in elem` is a generator expression. It is used as an argument of `.join()`, this way, the extra parentheses need not to be used. Anyway, the `g = (str(i) for i in elem)` defines a generator named `g`, and then one can write `print(":".join(g))` just after the `g = ...` (the same indentation). The `str.join()` method accepts any iterable that returns strings. Because of that, it can consume also a generator or a generator expression.

Answer (score 7):

I'd go for:

```
for items in your_list:
    print (*items, sep=':')
```

This takes advantage of `print` as a function and doesn't require joins or explicit string conversion.

Comment: @Ashwini yeah... sometimes quite painful having to use `print` as a statement :-(

Comment: if nothing else should be done with result this is the best solution

Comment: @Jon and oleg: Well, it seems to *me* tricky. I was thinking about `print` being just a replacement for the later processing of items. I do not know. Possibly... *"Explicit is better than implicit."*

Answer (score 1):

Use a `list comprehension` and `str.join`:

Convert the integers to string(using `str()`) before joining them

```
>>> lis = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],['five','six']]
>>> print ("\n".join([ ":".join(map(str,x))   for x in lis]))
1:2
3:4
5:6
five:six
```

or:

```
>>> print ("\n".join([ ":".join([str(y) for y in x])   for x in lis]))
1:2
3:4
5:6
five:six
```