# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Tags: python

```
def stringToLek(red):
    lek = {}
    deo = red.strip().split("|")
    lek["ser_br"] = int(deo[0])
    lek["fab_naziv"] = deo[1]
    lek["gen_naziv"] = deo[2]
    lek["kol_leka"] = int(deo[3])
    lek["c_leka"] = float(deo[4])
    return lek
def  lekToString(lek):
    return '|'.join([lek['ser_br'], lek['fab_naziv'], lek['gen_naziv'], lek['c_leka'], lek['kol_leka']])
```

.................................................................................

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python How to print list of list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251935/python-how-to-print-list-of-list)

Comment: `join` method works on (lists of) strings. You're trying to use integers. Convert them first, with `str()`.

Comment: Would you care to phrase a question, to explain what you are trying to achieve and what fails? Currently, people landing on your question must guess all that by themselves if they want to benefit from the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def  lekToString(lek):
return '|'.join([str(lek['ser_br']), str(lek['fab_naziv']), str(lek['gen_naziv']), str(lek['c_leka']), str(lek['kol_leka'])])
```

Answer (score 4):

All the arguments to `join()` must be strings.  It chokes at your first one, `lek['ser_br']` because that is not a string,  but rather an `int`.  `lek["kol_leka"]` and `lek["c_leka"]` will have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead you should define a class to implement this behavior?

```
class Lek:
    def __init__(self, red):
        deo = red.strip().split("|")
        self.ser_br = int(deo[0])
        self.fab_naziv = deo[1]
        self.gen_naziv = deo[2]
        self.kol_leka = int(deo[3])
        self.c_leka = float(deo[4])
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        # The order here is different than in the initializer, I guess it's a bug?
        return '|'.join([
            self.ser_br, self.fab_naziv, self.gen_naziv, self.c_leka, self.kol_leka])


def stringToLek(red):
    return Lek(red)

def  lekToString(lek):
    return str(lek)
```

The `def`s outside the class are pretty useless at this point, but I left them in just to show you what they would look like.

This may not be the ideal solution to your problem, but at least shows one refactoring which uses object-oriented programming to encapsulate the logic inside a class. Forcing the rest of your code to only use the methods of the class to interact with it feels like a drag when you first start, but it helps tremendously down the line by reducing the internal coupling between different parts of your code.

You could also solve this by having `lek` be a subclass of `str`. There are challenges with that, though.  See e.g. https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-list-and-dict-in-python/ (it discusses `dict` rather than `str`, but the issues are similar).  In practice, if you are careful, you can inherit from `str` but you'll have to override `__new__` instead of `__init__`.

```py
class Lek(str):
    def __new__(cls, seq):
        self = super().__new__(cls, seq)
        deo = seq.strip().split("|")
        self.ser_br = int(deo[0])
        self.fab_naziv = deo[1]
        self.gen_naziv = deo[2]
        self.kol_leka = int(deo[3])
        self.c_leka = float(deo[4])
        return self
```