# Print list of list using list comprehension

Tags: python, printing, list-comprehension

List 'a' can be printed as follows (CODE1):

```
a = [[4, 5], [2, 6]] 
print(*a, sep='\n')
```

The output (OP1) is:

```
[4, 5]
[2, 6]
```

I want the sublists to be printed in tab separated form. This can be done using loop as follows (CODE2):

```
for b in a:
print(*b, sep='\t')
```

Its output (OP2) is:

```
4   5
2   6
```

Can I get OP2 by modifying CODE1? I think list comprehension would be one of the routes of achieving this.

---

**Questions referred**

- [Python How to print list of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251935/python-how-to-print-list-of-list)
- [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.join` with generator expressions:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(i) for i in l) for l in a))
```

This outputs:

```
4 5
2 6
```

Comment: Can I ask a follow-up question?

Comment: Best to ask a new question in SO